# Apache Tomcat from 6.0.36 to 6.0.37 (windows server)

Tags: windows, tomcat6

I have a Apache Tomcat 6.0.36 installed on a windows server and would like to upgrade to 6.0.37

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what OS you are running. It's been a while since I've done this but for [32 bit Windows download](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) the archive, stop the Tomcat service, **move** the existing Tomcat folder to a backup location, **copy** the contents of your *conf* and *bin* folders from the old location to the new one and restart the service.

If something does not work move the new Tomcat folder to a backup location and restore the original.

Would be good to provide what OS you are using and what method you used to install Tomcat originally here.

Comment: The server is Windows 2008.  I inherited the server, so I cannot tell you the method used to install originally